# How to us Maven PDF Plugin to generate PDF from Surefire Report?

Tags: pdf, report, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-site-plugin, maven-pdf-plugin

after running my JUnit tests I use the Maven Surefire Report plugin (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-report-plugin/) to generate a HTML test report. This results in the following file:

```
./target/site/surefire-report.html
```

I know that there is a Maven PDF plugin to generate PDF files (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pdf-plugin/surefire-report.html). But I don't manage to get it working. I included it in my pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-pdf-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>pdf</id>
      <phase>test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>pdf</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>/tmp</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I try to run it I get an error that some source directory doesn't exist:

```
  ...
  [mvn] [INFO] [pdf:pdf {execution: default-cli}]
  [mvn] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [mvn] [INFO] Building VB Common
  [mvn] [INFO]    task-segment: [pdf:pdf]
  [mvn] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [mvn] [INFO] [pdf:pdf {execution: default-cli}]
  [mvn] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [mvn] [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
  [mvn] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [mvn] [INFO] Error during document generation: Source directory doesn't exists (/home/user/myproject/src/site).
  [mvn]
  ...
```

The error is not so surprising as I don't have a ./src/site folder.
But how can I configure the PDF plugin so it takes my HTML report from ./target/site/surefire-report.html as source file for the PDF?

Comment: Guy, if an answer is OK for you, please accept it (Raghuram or mine, no matter, but promote it)

Answer (score 4):

I don't have any problem including my report into pdf :

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<build>
    <extensions>
        <!-- Enabling the use of FTP -->
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>

    <plugins>
        <!-- Génération d'un PDF à l'identique du site maven -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pdf-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pdf</id>
                    <phase>site</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>pdf</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <!-- Gestion des plugins pour ce projet et ses sous modules -->
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Indication de compilation sur la version de Java à utiliser -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <!-- Gestion du tagage des releases -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tagBase>http://svn.xxx.fr.sopra/corprepo/svn/myproject/repository/tags/</tagBase>
                    <scmCommentPrefix>[DEV#GCL]</scmCommentPrefix>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Gestion de la fabrication du site maven -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <locales>fr</locales>
                    <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Génération d'un PDF à l'identique du site maven -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pdf-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pdf</id>
                        <phase>site</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>pdf</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Reporting & GCL - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>/src/main/config/checkstyle-sopra.xml</configLocation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>summary</report>
                        <report>modules</report>
                        <report>project-team</report>
                        <report>mailing-list</report>
                        <report>cim</report>
                        <report>issue-tracking</report>
                        <report>license</report>
                        <report>scm</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

And my src/main/pdf.xml

```xml
<document xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/DOCUMENT/1.0.1"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/DOCUMENT/1.0.1 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/document-1.0.1.xsd"
outputName="${project.artifactId}">

     <meta>
      <title>Maven PDF Plugin</title>
      <author>The Apache Maven Project</author>
 </meta>

 <toc name="Table of Contents">
      <item name="Introduction" ref="index.apt"/>

 </toc>

 <cover>
      <coverTitle>${project.name}</coverTitle>
      <coverSubTitle>v. ${project.version}</coverSubTitle>
      <coverType>User Guide</coverType>
      <projectName>${project.name}</projectName>
      <projectLogo>images/logo_myorg.png</projectLogo>
      <companyName>${project.organization.name}</companyName>
      <companyLogo>images/logo_myorg.png</companyLogo>
 </cover>
```

I can't give you the PDF because of confidential policy, but it works fine :)

Comment: where is the content of index.apt supposed to be located?

Comment: 5 years later, it's a bit difficult, but looking at my current workspace, it's :
/src/site/pdf.xml

Hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pdf-plugin/pdf-mojo.html#docDescriptor) of maven pdf plugin, the plugin needs a `file that contains the DocumentModel of the PDF to generate.` It is by default `src/site/pdf.xml`, which is why the plugin fails when it does not find this file.

The plugin is intended to generate the pdf version of the report generated by the maven site plugin.  As such, it generates the pdf versions of all reports for the project, which would include the surefire-report, if configured.

Comment: How does such a pdf.xml should look like? I tried: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/DECORATION/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/DECORATION/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/decoration-1.0.0.xsd">
  <body>
    <menu name="Surefire Report" href="target/site/surefire-report.html"/>
    <menu ref="reports"/>
  </body>
</project>

But this results in a NullPointerException

Comment: In addition I still have the problem, that even if I define such a pdf.xml, it still scans my subcomponents ./src/site directories which don't exist...

Comment: @Peter. Refer to http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pdf-plugin/usage.html for the pdf.xml. Perhaps the plugin source code repository has more info.

Comment: I already tried to go through the documentation... without luck. I can't get this plugin running :-(. One would expect that something like the pdf generation of a surefire report is supported without having to go through bigger efforts?

Comment: @Peter. The plugin site has a pdf link (left menu) which does generate a pdf report for their site:)  That's why I suggested browsing their repository.