# How to generate pdf report of junit test results?

Tags: java, maven, pdf, junit

```
I have a maven project and want to generate pdf report of my junit test results. I used Surefire and pdf plug-in as well. 
my pom looks like 
/*<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>                  <outputDirectory>D:\backups\third\aristocrat_template_project\game-jars\queenOfTheNile_html</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>         
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>        
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pdf-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pdf</id>
                        <phase>site</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>pdf</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>  
</build>
```

*/
    In my target site folder html files are generated but does not contains the report related to junit results. I also got a pdf file under target->pdf folder but it does not contain any information related to project or junit result. Thanks !

Comment: I vote this for the worst question I have ever seen on SO - wait is there actually a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this: [How to us Maven PDF Plugin to generate PDF from Surefire Report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920842/how-to-us-maven-pdf-plugin-to-generate-pdf-from-surefire-report)
you can use any (at least all I know) test coverage tool (like cobertura, jacoco) and will generate raports itselfes.
You can as well use cucumber test framework for very friendly reports, but that's a lof of effort to create cucumber tests.